# :db.error/connection-released the connection has been released in Datomic

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm running my Transactor(**EC2**) and Datomic(**DynamoDB**) on **AWS** and after a while, I started getting the following error which I did not understand anything:

```
:db.error/connection-released The connection has been released.
....
```

Also, I was running my app for a month before but did not get this error at the time.

Any ideas?, if this happens regularly should I re-establish database connection in app code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that when transactor instance **reboots** I get that error so I found a work around for this problem here is the code:

```
(defn establish-conn
  []
  (try
      (d/create-database (conf/get :db-uri))
      (reset! conn (d/connect (conf/get :db-uri)))
    (catch Throwable t
      (println "Could not establish db conn." t))))

(defn fix-if-conn-ex
  ;;getting exception's error message
  [err-msg]
  (when (str/includes? err-msg ":db.error/connection-released")
    (db/establish-conn)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you ever calling [release](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/release) on the DB? That's one thing I think could cause this, once you call release you can't use any Datomic connections again for the life of the app. Connections are really lightweight, so there's very rarely a reason to call this function.

Comment: no I did not, after deploying my app to aws I got this error couple of hours later which was odd.if I check this exception, and re-establish connection(d/connect "my-db-uri") would it work?

Comment: Also I found out that if transactor terminates and I create a new one, it deletes my table on DynamoDB :/ why does this happen, any ideas?